# How do I get my HTML to only show the amount of dice that I put on as val to be shown

Tags: html

When loaded the program asks you to prompt the number of dice you want to play with. I then want the program to only show that number of dice that you prompt but it always shows 6 dice.

Here is My code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    img {
      height: 150px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Click the button to see the roll of a die randomly selected</h1>
  <script>
    Val = window.prompt("Enter the number of dice to play with (1-5)");

    function roll() {
      var numShown = 0;
      for (var i = 1; i <= Val; i++) {
        var ran = Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1;
        document.getElementById('dieImg' + i).setAttribute("src", "dieImages/die" + ran + ".jpg")
      }
      if (ran <= 1) {
        numShown = 1;
      } else if (ran == 2) {
        numShown = 2;
      } else if (ran == 3) {
        numShown = 3;
      } else if (ran == 4) {
        numShown = 4;
      } else if (ran == 5) {
        numShown = 5;
      } else
        numShown = 6;
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "Die " + Val + " was selected and rolled to show " + numShown;
    }
  </script>
  <!-- Im thinking the mistake is here but I need these here to show images. -->
  <img id="dieImg1" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg">
  <img id="dieImg2" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg">
  <img id="dieImg3" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg">
  <img id="dieImg4" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg">
  <img id="dieImg5" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg">
  <hr>
  <button type="button" onclick="roll()">Click to Roll</button>
  <p id="display">--</p>
</body>

</html>
```

[This is what it looks like to prompt the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNn4s.png)
[Here I only want 3 dice to show instead of 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zknv9.png)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that all your images are shown no matter what is the random or the dice number
you should start by hiding them

```
<img id="dieImg1" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg" style="display: none;">
```

then in your for loop show them ( you'll be only showing the same number as *Val* )

```
document.getElementById('dieImg'+i).style.display = "block";
```